# Unable to update a json value in a loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a js code in which I need to update 1 JSON based on the condition from another JSON. Here are my code.

```js
var a = [{
  "a": "Not Started"
}, {
  "b": "Not Started"
}, {
  "c": "Not Started"
}, {
  "d": "Not Started"
}, {
  "e": "Not Started"
}];

var b = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Stage": "c"
}];

a.forEach((obj) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a)) {
    a.value = 'complete'
    if (key == b[0].Stage)
      break
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. Check what is the `Stage` value in `b` JSON variable. then moving to my `a` JSON variable and looping over it. If `Key` matches, the `Stage` value, till the particular key, I want to update the value in `a` variable to `complete`, rest, just return as it is.

From the above snippet, the expected output is.

```
[{
  "a": "complete"
}, {
  "b": "complete"
}, {
  "c": "complete"
}, {
  "d": "Not Started"
}, {
  "e": "Not Started"
}];
```

Since the `Stage` value in `b` stage is `c`.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: 1. a is an array not an object, so there isn't any entries for a. 2. same goes for a.value (even if referencing the the obj it should be obj[key] not obj.value. 3. an array.forEach does not usually modifies the array, there is an array.map() for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = [{
  "a": "Not Started"
}, {
  "b": "Not Started"
}, {
  "c": "Not Started"
}, {
  "d": "Not Started"
}, {
  "e": "Not Started"
}];

var b = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Stage": "c"
}];

var idx = a.findIndex(x => Object.keys(x)[0] === b[0].Stage);

for (var i = 0; i <= idx; i++){
    const key = Object.keys(a[i])[0];
    a[i][key] = "complete";
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Hey @Ran Turner. This is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton, mate.

Comment: You're more then welcome my friend. would appreciate the upvote if possible (:

Answer (score 3):

if the keys of objects are alphabetical characters (assuming the example you have provided isn't a generalisation), you use take advantage of the ordering of character codes:

```js
const a = [{
  "a": "Not Started"
}, {
  "b": "Not Started"
}, {
  "c": "Not Started"
}, {
  "d": "Not Started"
}, {
  "e": "Not Started"
}];

const b = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Stage": "c"
}];


for (obj of a) {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0]
  if (key.charCodeAt(0) <= b[0]["Stage"].charCodeAt(0)) {
    obj[key] = "complete"
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

if the alphabetical order isn't the case, you can follow the solution above

Answer (score 2):

More generic solution, in case where `b` can contain more than 1 element:

```js
var a = [{
  "a": "Not Started"
}, {
  "b": "Not Started"
}, {
  "c": "Not Started"
}, {
  "d": "Not Started"
}, {
  "e": "Not Started"
}];

var b = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Stage": "b"
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "Stage": "c"
}];

const currStage = b.sort((a,b) => b["Id"] - a["Id"])[0]["Stage"]

a = a.map(e => {
  const [[letter, state]] = Object.entries(e)
  const inStage = letter.charCodeAt(0) <= currStage.charCodeAt(0)
  const currState = inStage ? "completed" : state
  return Object.fromEntries([[letter, currState]])
})

console.log(a)
```